# How to add routerlink instead "a href" with string interpolation in angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, string-interpolation, routerlink

I have a full sentence like

```
I have read the <a href="xyz">Terms and Conditions</a>, <a href="xyz" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="xyz">Legal Notice</a> and I fully agree to it without any concerns whatever blahblah
```

Now we want to use RouterLink instead of HTML -Tag. But we dont' want to split the translation into multiple parts and concatenate it in the end (which sometimes doesnt even work because the link order varies depending on the language somehow).

Is there a solution how to achieve this in Angular?

Answer (score -1):

Try Using:

**Component.ts**

```
xyz:any = '/page1';
```

**component.html**

```
I have read the <a routerLink="{{xyz}}">Terms and Conditions</a>, <a routerLink="{{xyz}}" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="xyz">Legal Notice</a> and I fully agree to it without any concerns whatever blahblah
```

This will help you....